# Laravel - Flexible controllers and repository

Tags: laravel, repository

To create a flexible controller and to use the IoC of Laravel, one would do the following (say for a table `User`)

1. Create `interface UserInterface`
2. Create `class EloquentUserRepository implements UserInterface`
3. `App::bind` the `interface` to the `implement`

But, then you also create a model `User` that extends `Eloquent`, and your `EloquentUserRepository` then basically calls this model. Other than the provided Eloquent functions, if you create a custom function or relation in `User`, then you need to create a function in `EloquentUserRepository` that simply returns that. Isn't that repetitive? Is there a way to directly have the model implement the interface?

Comment: I think [this is what you are looking for](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.U3iQO_mSySo).

Comment: No, the `UserRepository` in that example just links the functions to `User` model. That is repetitive. They are one and the same thing. I want to eliminate that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't that repetitive?

Yes. Unless you have a specific need - you can run the risk of 'over engineering' or 'over abstracting' your application.

If you dont plan to swap out your 'users' with anything in the future - there is no need to do so much. Just because you "can" do something doesnt mean you "should".

You could just have UserInterface - then your model does

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface
```

and just skip the Repository completely.

Comment: Well, the whole point is that in the future if I want to swap Eloquent for another DB, I can easily do so. So I do want to basically keep an Eloquent way of implementing my interface, and if I wanted to move on to something else, then I can in the future. I just don't want to create two files (the model and the repository) to do this

Comment: Eloquent is not a DB. A DB is mySQl/PostSQL/Sqlite etc. Eloquent IS your DB abstraction layer. Eloquent already allows you to swap DB. If you want to abstract Eloquent itself - then you are by definition abstracting an abstract - which is way way way over engineered.

Comment: Kk, that makes sense. Another issue though: say I want to find someone by age, then in Eloquent, I can use `queryAge($query, $age)`, but then in my interface, I want to have a function called `public function age($age)`. Using the `class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface` returns error since my `User` has a function called `queryAge(...)` but my interface has `age(...)`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you have an interface with the function age() you MUST implement that in your User Model - thats the whole point of an interface - it is a binding contract that says a particular function will exist on any implementation of that interface.

Comment: Yes, I understand that! What I meant was that with Laravel Eloquent, your build your query using the notation `scopeAge($query, $age)`. So if my model implements the interface, then it has to have a function called `age()` but Eloquent needs to have a function called `queryAge()`, and I don't want to call the interface `age()` as `queryAge()`

Comment: So does your interface "need" to have a function called age() in the first place? Can you not either; 1. Remove age() or 2. rename age() to scopeAge()?

Comment: Well, the reason is because it is an interface, and so having `age()` makes more sense than `scopeAge()`. And also, with Eloquent, it will automatically pass the `$query` itself, and in another implementation, this may change, and I may not need to pass the query directly

Comment: So this makes sense and works, except for my last concern with the scope.